# C: Read integers into dynamically allocated array, space separated and with other chars to ignore/replace

Tags: python, c, translate

Basically my problem is that I'm trying to manually translate stuff that Python3 does easily into a C program. My first hurdle is literally input comprehension. Here is the sample input:

```
5
12
34 10
22 20 55
123 30 x 99
```

So as we can see, there are numbers, spaces, and characters in this input. I handled it in Python pretty easily, like so:

```
n = int(input()) #first line is always a single integer
matrix = [[' ' for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)] #declaring matrix of just space chars

for i in range(1,n):
    line = input().split(' ') #gets rid of all spaces
    for j in range(len(line)):
        try:
            matrix[i][j] = int(line[j])
            matrix[j][i] = int(line[j]) #mirrors same value on opposite part of the matrix
        except:
            matrix[i][j] = 'x'
            matrix[j][i] = 'x'
```

This results in the following matrix:

```
[[' ', 12, 34, 22, 123]
[12, ' ', 10, 20, 30]
[34, 10, ' ', 55, 'x']
[22, 20, 55, ' ', 99]
[123, 30, 'x', 99, ' ']]
```

So basically, I want to figure out how to do this in C. I have seen posts about how to read inputs dynamically, how to receive space-separated integers, and how to malloc integer space, but I have no idea how to put all of that stuff together. I would really appreciate some help. Ideally I want to store all these integers into a 2D array of integers like shown above.

EDIT: This is as far as I've gotten (code butchered from other people's helpful answers):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int n; //number of cities
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%d\n", n);
    int *matrix = (int*)malloc(n*n*sizeof(int));
    
    int i=0, j=0; 
    int *line = matrix; 
    char temp; 
    for (int k=0;k<n;k++)
    {
        do { 
                scanf("%d%c", &line[i], &temp); 
                i++; 
        } while(temp != '\n'); 
   
        for(j=0; j<i; j++) { 
                printf("%d ", matrix[j]); 
        } 
        printf("\n");
    }
    free(matrix);
    free(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this code:

```
5
5
12
12
34 10
12 34 10
22 20 55
12 34 10 22 20 55
123 30 x 99
```

^From above, first '5' is my input, second '5' is outputted, first '12' is my input, second is outputted, and so on. Code breaks in the last line. I understand that each time, it dumps everything stored in the 'buffer' that is the int * matrix. I don't know how to handle other characters like the 'x'. Ideally I would like to replace the 'x' in the matrix with a -1 or something.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219981/discussion-on-question-by-cyber101-c-read-integers-into-dynamically-allocated-a).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is really a mistake to mix scanf with getchar, but I believe the correct way to avoid scanf here is to pass `n` as a parameter (eg, read it from argv[1] rather than from the input stream).  Also, your python is not really a matrix, but is a list of lists, and it would probably be cleaner to use a list of lists in the C implementation.  But here is one approach to using a large array.

```
#include <ctype.h>                                                                 
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <stdarg.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
struct entry {                                                                     
        enum { unknown, number, character } type;                                  
        union {                                                                    
                int v;                                                             
                char x;                                                            
        } value;                                                                   
};                                                                                 
                                                                                   
static int                                                                         
die(const char *fmt, ...)                                                          
{                                                                                  
        va_list ap;                                                                
        va_start(ap, fmt);                                                         
        vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);                                                 
        va_end(ap); 
        fputc('\n', stderr);                                                               
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                        
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(void) {                                                                       
        int n, c = '\n', p = EOF, row = 0;                                         
        if( scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1 ) {                                      
                die("Invalid input in row %d (%c)", row, c);                       
        }                                                                          
        struct entry *matrix = calloc(n * n, sizeof *matrix);                      
        struct entry *t = matrix - 1, *e = matrix + n * n;                         
        while( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {                                           
                if( isdigit(c) ) {                                                 
                        if( t->type == character ) {                               
                                die("Invalid input in row %d (%c)", row, c);       
                        }                                                          
                        t->type = number;                                          
                        t->value.v = t->value.v * 10 + c - '0';                    
                } else if( isspace(c) && c != p ) {                                
                        t += 1;                              
                        if( t >= e ) {
                                die("Invalid input in row %d (%c)", row, c);
                        }
                        if( c == '\n' ) {
                                t->type = character;
                                t->value.x = ' ';
                                t = matrix + n * ++row;
                        }
                } else {
                        if( t->type != unknown ) {
                                die("Invalid input in row %d (%c)", row, c);
                        }
                        t->type = character;
                        t->value.x = c;
                }
                p = c;
        }

        /* Display the matrix */
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < n; j++ ) {
                        t = matrix + (( j > i ) ? (n * j + i) : (n * i + j));
                        switch( t->type ) {
                        case number:
                                printf("%8d", t->value.v);
                                break;
                        case unknown:
                                printf("%8s", "??");
                                break;
                        case character:
                                printf("     '%c'", t->value.x);
                        }
                }
                putchar('\n');
        }
}
```

This solution is not as robust against whitespace issues in the input as a scanf solution would be, and does not handle runs of space or mixed space and tabs.  Fixing that is left as an exercise for the reader.